Hide page count from the go to section of the pdf toolbar when pdf is opened in browser
From java side I am converting tiff images to PDF like below.
Rectangle pagesize = new Rectangle(maxWidth, maxHeight);
Document document  = new Document(pagesize);
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, output);
document.open();
    
for (int imageIndex = 0; imageIndex < numPages; imageIndex++) {
  img = images.get(imageIndex);
  img.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);
  document.setPageSize(new Rectangle(maxWidth, maxHeight));
  document.add(img);
  document.newPage();
  }
    
document.close();

and then from the angular side , I am using window.open to show the PDF file like this
.subscribe(fileUrl => {
  dialogRef.close();
  windowRef = window.open(..${fileUrl}#toolbar=0, '_blank', 'width=800,height=600');
  this.addToAttachmentManager(windowRef, processId);
  },
  () => dialogRef.close()
);

When the pdf is opened in the browser , I want to hide the Total page count only from the pdf toolbar panel


That's not possible. The PDF page controls are determined by the browser being used to view the document at a level outside of what JS/CSS can reach.

By the way, you seem to be adding an unnecessary blank page at the end, as you're calling newPage() even at the last iteration.

Thanks for the above info.
#toolbar=0 hide the complete toolbar in the browser widow. now I just need to find a way to add current page number on pages. can we do this?

You cannot really block PDF reader Overviews as they are inside user controls.
It can only work for some users some of the time.
Toolbar=0 was a legacy I.E. Acrobat toggle 0=off 1=on (still works there) and only really useful for inhouse use (which can be done different ways with plug-ins). Traditionally the toolbar=# was reflected internally by user F8 as shown below the user can switch toolbar back on.
If you set the Acrobat fragment to .pdf#toolbar=0 it only has partial affect in a few browser types, not all. So here it was used with a remote document to autohide the topbar navigator but it does not affect the Edge Navigation sidebar on the right.

Without changing web toolbar=0, the same user can switch to installed Acrobat Reader and then toolbars are F8 on/off controls like the sidebars.

Each browser "Plugin" will have different methods and some will ignore toolbar=0.
Up-to-date Mozilla like browser a plugin ignoring Toolbar fragment.

Same browser same link initially works with Acrobat per design.

User presses F8 same as the other plugin but now it sets acrobat toolbar on.

